# Roboto typeface for entire application

Tags: android, performance, typeface

I am trying to use Roboto Typeface for entire application. Creating typeface object and applying it on all fields required works but tedious since number of fields have grown apart findViewId() on each TextView, Button will degrade performance.
I am trying to make configuration in  as most of them suggested on internet but i am not able to use Roboto. i get "sans-serif-light" as not recognized.

Please suggest which method to follow.

Comment: Just a reminder, Roboto may be available on Android 4.0 and above. If you want to use a "custom typeface", you have to do it programmatically.

Comment: I am using ICS; so, only method is to do programmatic-ally ... Based on number of textview and buttons it's quite a tiresome task

Comment: IF your minSdkVersion is ICS (v.14), then it is most likely that the devices has Roboto. However, it doesn't mean it will be the default font. Talking about performance and minimizing memory and cpu usage, I suggest use and reuse static methods (Singleton style) to load the font from Assets to avoid extra allocations. CTRL+C and CRTL+V are good friends too :P

Comment: That will Optimize code to an extent. i wonder why google has maintained using roboto in this way... Thank you for responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class,

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {
static Typeface Roboto_Bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(Global.mainActivity.getAssets(), "Roboto-Bold.ttf");
static Typeface Roboto_Regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(Global.mainActivity.getAssets(), "Roboto-Regular.ttf");
```

and add below code in constructors, use CustomTextView in entire application instead of TextView

```
try {
    int style = getTypeface().getStyle();
    if (style == (Typeface.BOLD)) {
      isBold = true;
    }
 } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (isBold)
      this.setTypeface(Roboto_Bold);
else
       this.setTypeface(Roboto_Regular);
```

----- updated,

i recently found that custom typeface will stored in native memory at huge memory consumption. So creating typeface inside the custom TextView class is going to fill native memory to large extent (300 Mb in my case) depends on number of instance of TextView get created.

So better create a Static Typeface object which the TextView refers hence reduces memory consumption (20 Mb in my case)

if you have more than one custom View's using Typeface consider global static Typeface